# Visual Studio 2008 - vftable pointer incorrect? Debug mode crashes, Release is fine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, crash, release

I'm currently facing an issue with VS08. I got the following (simplified) class structure:

```
class CBase
{
    public:
    virtual void Func() = 0;
};

class CDerived : public CBase
{
public:
    void Func();
};
```

This code is working fine in Release Mode, but when I try to run a Debug Build it's instantly crashing at `new CDerived`.

Further Analysis brought me to the point where I was able to locate the crash. It's crashing at CBase::CBase (the compiler-generated constructor). More precisely it's crashing at `04AE46C6  mov         dword ptr [eax],offset CBase::`vftable' (505C2CCh) `.

Any clues? Release Mode is fine, but I can't properly Debug with it.

Comment: You have a buffer overrun elsewhere.

Comment: there's no `main` function...

Comment: How about posting a complete example that reproduces the crash?

Comment: Well posting a complete example didn't seem possible, as the error only occures in this one project and - even with removed referenced to other classes - works fine. 
I actually solved this issue now. It seems to be an optimization issue, which led to the vftable to be a pointer to an invalid position.

Answer (score 1):

> Release Mode is fine

Nope, it appears to be fine. My guess is in debug the memory is overwritten somehow. Since there's no way to tell just from the code you posted, here's what you can do.

I assume you create the object somewhere with:

```
CBase* p = new CDerived;
```

or similar. In debug mode, set a **memory breakpoint** at `p`'s location. You can set it to monitor 4 bytes. Visual C++ (like most compilers) will keep the vfptr as the first thing in the class, so this breakpoint will track whether that location overwritten. If the breakpoint is hit before you call the function where it crashes, there's your problem (and the call-stack will show you why it's overwritten).

It could be a lot of reasons - you could be overrunning some memory and overwriting the object (as Erik suggested) - the release version might resolve the call directly to prevent the overhead of the dynamic dispatch and that would explain why it's not crashing.

It could also be that you call `delete` on the object and the debug version actually zeroes out the memory, whereas the release version doesn't. No way to tell just from that.

Answer (score 1):

Necro-posting a bit here, but there's a point I want to make for future visitors...

As others have said, this was probably a memory corruption or free+reuse issue.  You should not assume that it was a compiler bug just because you were able to eliminate the crash by changing compiler settings or rearranging code.  If this is a corruption bug, what you probably did was to move the corruption to some memory that does not cause your program to crash--not in your current build, on your current OS & architecture, anyway.

Simply getting to the point of not crashing may have been sufficient for your immediate needs, but meanwhile you did not learn to avoid whatever practice led you to write the bug in the first place.  There's a long-standing proverb amongst engineers and probably a fair number of other disciplines:

"What goes away by itself can come back by itself."

It may be one of the most true and important proverbs in any form of engineering.  If you did not see the bug die, by your own hand, you should always feel anxious about it.  It should bother you, deeply.  The bug is probably still there, waiting for the night of your next milestone before it rears its head again.

Luchian Grigore gave good advice on finding the real problem with a memory breakpoint.